# Is there a word for something (a parameter not a person) that is being affected?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

My sentence reads something like, "These parameters are being affected on varying a and b conditions."
I want it to sound like, " The affectees of parameters a and b are ... "
I don't know if I can use affectee here or if that is even a word.  I have found rare usage of this word affectee and never for a parameter. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your two sentences don't mean the same thing at all. In your first sentence a and b are described as conditions. In the second sentence a and b are described as parameters.  It is not clear whether the parameters are affecting the conditions or the conditions are affecting the parameters. Please can you resolve this confusion otherwise answers will make no sense.

Answer (score 1):

By "variable", I assume you mean the *value of a function* that is partly or completely defined by parameters *a* and *b*.

If a function f(*a*,*b*,...) is affected by the parameters *a* and *b*, it is conventional to say that the function f depends on *a* and *b*. That being the case, we could argue that the function is a *dependent* of *a* and *b*.

> A function is a mathematical relationship in which the values of a single dependent variable are determined by the values of one or more independent variables. Function means the dependent variable is determined by the independent variable(s)
>
> [Columbia edu](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/sipa/math/variables.html)

From this perspective, rather than coining a new word *affectee*, one might use *dependent*. This is not as far as I know a widespread usage but is easily understood.

For example, "If the values of functions {or variables in your sentence} **f**(*a*,*b*, ...) and **g**(*a*,*b*, ...) are partly or wholly determined by *a* and *b*, the dependents of parameters *a* and *b* are ... **f** and **g**"

Answer (score 0):

How about, "The parameters affected by varying a and b are..."?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find this word in the *Shorter Oxford English Dictionary* but it is in [*the Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/affectee).

> **affectee**, Noun (plural affectees)     One who, or that which, is affected.

From this definition, then, it can be presumed that this is a term that can be applied generally.

Here is, however, the definition from [*Lexico*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/affectee).

> **affectee**, Noun (mainly in Pakistani English) a person affected or harmed as the result of an event or action.
> ‘our doctors and medical staff are actively involved in examining the earthquake affectees’

Nevertheless, this [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22affectee%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) shows that, since recently,  this word has  been used consistently in linguistics. It is not possible to determine what it is applied to in linguistics but it is very probable that it is not restricted to human beings.

To confirm that it is a term that can be applied to other entities than human beings, here are a couple of examples from the preceding page. This type of usage is however rare compared to the  very large use of this word in linguistics, which tends to corroborate,  Lexico's mentioning that it is mainly found in Pakistani English.

[Model-Based Systems Engineering with OPM and SysML - Page 169](https://books.google.fr/books?id=dY9PDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA169&dq=%22affectee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9r8OkiJLtAhUOyxoKHbhaDuUQ6AEwA3oECGEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22affectee%22&f=false)  both the agent Baker and the instrument Oven must be present throughout a Cake Baking process. Fig. 13.8 The same object playing the roles instrument and affectee: Moving Truck is an instrument of Moving and an affectee of Servicing

[Transactions on High-Performance Embedded Architectures and ...](https://books.google.fr/books?id=N9UQxb_wnioC&pg=PA76&dq=%22affectee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9r8OkiJLtAhUOyxoKHbhaDuUQ6AEwSHoECA0QAg#v=onepage&q=%22affectee%22&f=false) 4.1 Characterization of Affectors and Affectees Fig. 2 and 3 show the cumulative distribution of dynamic branches according to the number of affector and affectee correlations they have. The number of correlations can not exceed 400 since we ...

According to those two sources you too should be able to use that word, unless the context is that taken up by [**user Anton**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/552358/349876)'s answer.